# Can someone be an ATPL holder while having Pineal Cyst?

Tags: atpl

Does anyone know if I can become an ATPL holder with pineal cyst (2cm).I have no symptoms and was discovered accidentally because as a family we do MRI every 5 years (It is nothing it is just a family custom?I suppose)I have asked medical experts and I dont know some say yes and some say no...

17 years old
Europe-->EASA

Comment: Sounds like you’ve asked everyone but the aviation medical examiner who is the one who can actually answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the EASA easy access rules for medical requirements for conditions that are immediately disqualifying. I'm not sure what your condition falls under but in all likeliness it requires "further assessment". This can mean anything from a letter from your doctor, consultation with your country's transport authority, to additional medical evaluations.

Getting your first medical is not cheap but not compared to the cost of learning to fly, it's not that bad. By getting ahead of things now, you not only buy some peace of mind but also show prospective employers that you are serious about flying.